# Using ArcGIS Pro field calculator: check values one column and enter specific data in a second column

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, field-calculator, python-parser

I have two fields and I want to use field calculator to check the column Datierun_1 (alias is Datierung) for certain words (in this case "Achaemenid"). In case it finds a match it should enter a digit (in this case 4) in the field DatePhase01. In case there is no match it should do nothing.

[image]
I have been trying it with:

```
def check(Datierun_1):
    if Datierun_1 == "Achaemenid":
    return 4
```

but it seems not to work and I have no clue why. I am obviously an absolute beginner.

Comment: Python is the world's easiest programming language to learn, mostly because the formatting manages all the flow of control. But this means you actually have to pay attention to indenting.  The code you originally posted seems to be missing two lines, compared to the image; both were indented incorrectly.  What you have in the image should give a syntax error.  You probably need to work though the first few chapters of a Python book before you start in ArcPy.

Comment: Thank you for advice, no idea how I managed to get "else" on the same level with "def" and I noticed that it works fine without "else", adding all the other conditions with "elif".

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to test if `Datierun_1` is *exactly* equal to `"Achaemenid"`:

```
def check(Datierun_1):
    if Datierun_1 == "Achaemenid":
        return 4
```

If you are trying to test if `Datierun_1` *contains* `"Achaemenid"`:

```
def check(Datierun_1):
    if "Achaemenid" in Datierun_1:
        return 4
```

Notes:

- Indentation is mandatory in Python, it defines groups of statements. Your screenshot and code example should both fail with an `IndentationError` (or `SyntaxError`) as they are incorrectly indented
- Your screenshot has the following line

  ```
   else:
       return "Null"
  ```

  This line is both possibly incorrect and unnecessary.  Possibly incorrect because you're returning the text `"Null"` instead of an actual null value, which in Python is `None` (no quotes), unless you actually want the text `"Null"` in your column. And possibly unnecessary because if you don't explicitly return anything from a function, Python will implicitly return `None` automatically.